Proving that $\mu_x = \mu_{T(x)}$, where $\mu_x$ is the conditional measure associated to the $\sigma$-algebra of $T$-invariant sets
Here is the question I am thinking about:
Let $(X, \mathcal B, \mu, T)$ be a topological probability measure dynamical system. Let $\mathcal A$ be the sigma-algebra of $T$- invariant sets. Let $i^*: L^1(X, \mathcal B, \mu) \to L^1(X, \mathcal A, \mu)$ be the conditional expectation map. For each $x,$ let $\mu_x$ be the measure defined as follows
"$i^*: L^1(X, \mathcal B, \mu) \to L^1(X, \mathcal C, \mu)$ (where $\mathcal C \subseteq \mathcal B$) defined by $f \to i^*(f)$ where $\forall x \in X$ there exists $\mu_x = \mu_x^{\mathcal C}$ such that $$ i^*(f)(x) = \int_X fd\mu_x.$$"
Prove that $\mu_x = \mu_{T(x)}$ for almost all $x \in X.$
Some thoughts:
I guess I should prove that for any function $f \in L^1(X, \mathcal B, \mu)$ we have $i^*(f) \circ T = i^*(f).$ But actually I do not know how to do that.
Any help will be greatly appreciated!

This follows from the characterization of conditional expectations. Recall that for $(X,\mathcal{B})$ a measurable space and $\mathcal{A}\leq \mathcal{B}$ a sub-$\sigma$-algebra, the conditional expectation operator
$$
\mathbb{E}_\mu(\bullet|\mathcal{A}):L^1(X,\mathcal{B},\mu;\mathbb{R})\to L^1(X,\mathcal{A},\mu;\mathbb{R})
$$
is characterized (modulo $\mu$) by the following two properties:

$\forall f\in L^1(X,\mathcal{B},\mu;\mathbb{R}): \mathbb{E}_\mu(f|\mathcal{A})$ is $\mathcal{A}$-measurable.
$\forall f\in L^1(X,\mathcal{B},\mu;\mathbb{R}),\forall A\in\mathcal{A}: \mathbb{E}_\mu(\chi_A\, f) = \mathbb{E}_\mu(\chi_A\, \mathbb{E}_\mu(f|\mathcal{A}))$.

See e.g. Einsiedler & Ward's Ergodic Theory for further details.

Recall the change of variables formula for conditional expectation (see e.g. Conditional expectation is $T$-invariant in a measure preserving system.):
Lemma: Let $(X,\mathcal{B})$ and $(Y,\mathcal{C})$ be measurable spaces. Then for any measurable $T:(X,\mathcal{B})\to (Y,\mathcal{C})$, for any sub-$\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A}\leq\mathcal{C}$, for any probability measure $\mu$ on $X$ and for any measurable $f:Y\to\mathbb{R}$, one has
$$
\mathbb{E}_{T_\ast(\mu)}(f|\mathcal{A})\circ T = \mathbb{E}_\mu(f\circ T| T^{-1}(\mathcal{A})) \mod\mu.
$$
In particular if $\mu$ is $T$ invariant and $\mathcal{A}=\mathcal{I}(T)$ is the $T$-invariant sub-$\sigma$-algebra of $T$-invariant subsets, then one has
$$
\mathbb{E}_{\mu}(f|\mathcal{I}(T))\circ T = \mathbb{E}_\mu(f\circ T| \mathcal{I}(T)) \mod\mu. \quad\quad(\dagger)
$$
Translating this to conditional measure formalism (whenever applicable, e.g. in the case when the measurable spaces are standard) one obtains
$$
\mu^{\mathcal{I}(T)}_{T(x)} = T_\ast\left(\mu^{\mathcal{I}(T)}_x\right) \mod\mu.
$$
(Here $\mu^{\mathcal{I}(T)}_x$ is exactly the same object as your $\mu_x$.)

The claim is that for $\mu$-ae $x\in X$, $\mu_x^{\mathcal{I}(T)}$ is $T$-invariant. Switching over to the conditional expectation formalism, it suffices to see that the operator
$$
f\mapsto \mathbb{E}_\mu(f\circ T| \mathcal{I}(T))
$$
satisfies the two characterizing conditions for conditional expectation. By $(\dagger)$ above, for $f$ $\mathcal{B}$-measurable, $\mathbb{E}_\mu(f\circ T| \mathcal{I}(T))$ is the composition of two $\mathcal{A}$-measurable functions, hence is $\mathcal{A}$-measurable itself, verifying the first condition.
For the second condition, let $A\in\mathcal{I}(T)$, so that $T^{-1}(A)=A$ (aka $\chi_A\circ T=\chi_A$ in terms of characteristic functions). Then one has
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}_\mu(\chi_A \, \mathbb{E}_\mu(f\circ T| \mathcal{I}(T)))
&= 
\mathbb{E}_\mu(\chi_A \, \mathbb{E}_\mu(f| \mathcal{I}(T))\circ T)\\
&= 
\mathbb{E}_\mu((\chi_A \, \mathbb{E}_\mu(f| \mathcal{I}(T)))\circ T)\\
&= 
\mathbb{E}_{T_\ast(\mu)}(\chi_A \, \mathbb{E}_\mu(f| \mathcal{I}(T)))\\
&= 
\mathbb{E}_{\mu}(\chi_A \, \mathbb{E}_\mu(f| \mathcal{I}(T)))\\
&= 
\mathbb{E}_{\mu}(\chi_A \, f).
\end{align*}
